# Git branches on different server

Tags: git

I am new to git, I start use in it 2 month ago

My repository is hosted on a remote server outside our domain controller (Server 1 on bitbukket), I want to create a branch on a server hosted on our domain server, so the developer can commit their code on a internal server before merging and push on a remote server

This is the steps I followed :

1. I open the cloned repository on my station (cloned from server 1)
2. git remote add private //server2.domainname/GitFolder
3. git fetch private

`git fetch private` gives the below message

> fatal : //server2.domainname/GitFolder does not appear to be a git repository, fatal : could not read from remote repository

Comment: Why do you feel you need the extra layer of indirection?

Comment: *Is* `//server2.domainname/GitFolder` a git repository?  Is that folder readable, and does it actually contain the content?  If not, that would be why git is telling you it's not a repository/is not readable...

Comment: no it's not a repository, and yes it's readable, it's an empty folder

Comment: @Makoto : sometimes we have internet issue so we need to keep a version internal

Comment: Git's already a DVCS; you have an internal copy of the repository by virtue of it being on your local machine.  Of course this means that you can't actively *push* anywhere if your network is down, but it also means that this sort of thing isn't entirely critical to mitigate.  Think of it like this:  if your network goes down, you're not going to be deploying anything...